# Module Template/alternate layout Name language Override

Tags: custom-module, module-params

[image]

Is there a way that I can create a module template and give it a name with spaces?  At the moment it takes it's name from the file name, but that is not very neat for the user.  Can we create a language string to override this?  For example could we make the screenshot "default 2" instead.

How does Joomla! make default appear with a capital letter "Default"

And... as a second question.  I'd like to add a hint so I can show users what the options are via an image.  Would this be possible via a language string?  I only want to do it for this specific module and not all of the Joomla! modules.

Comment: There is the option to create your own custom field.

Comment: Does that mean there is no way to do this in Joomla?

Comment: @FFrewin I see what you mean now.  That would be the way to get my custom image.  Thank you.  Any idea about the other part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layout language key is built like this:

```
$key = strtoupper($module . '_LAYOUT_' . $value);
```

Where `$module` is the module name (including `mod_` prefix) and `$value` is the layout name. Example string for `mod_tags_popular` module's layout strings:

```
MOD_TAGS_POPULAR_LAYOUT_CLOUD="Cloud"
MOD_TAGS_POPULAR_LAYOUT_DEFAULT="Default"
```

The language key for module layouts provided by templates is built like this:

```
$key = strtoupper('TPL_' . $template->element . '_' . $module . '_LAYOUT_' . $value);
```

Where `$template->element` is the element/name of the template, `$module` is the module name (including `mod_` prefix) and `$value` is the layout name.

Example string for `mod_custom` module's `alternative.php` layout in `Protostar` template:

```
TPL_PROTOSTAR_MOD_CUSTOM_LAYOUT_ALTERNATIVE="Alternative"
```

Note, the string must be placed in the `.sys.ini` file, e.g. `en-GB.tpl_protostar.sys.ini`.

Comment: Wow, I genuinely didn't expect an answer.  So this means the language string needs to have a version for all of the possible template names?  That doesn't sound right, say it isn't so!

Comment: @Eoin you only need a string for the template the layout belongs to.

Comment: But a module layout can go with any template right?  Or am I misunderstanding

Comment: @Eoin, based on your screenshot I assumed you are shipping the layout as part of a template. If you're instead developing a module, the key doesn't need a template prefix. I have updated the answer to indicate this.